# How to stretch live type

Tags: html, css, svg

I'd like to stretch type to fill an entire area of a div, but am having trouble, as the scale() feature in CSS is kind of limiting (and also does some weird things to the div itself)

I know it is possible to turn the text into an svg and scale it that way, but I'd like to keep the text live as I've made a countdown feature.

Essentially I'd like the type to completely fill the box, stretching itself even as the type alters in width as the characters alternate.

Is this possible? Or am I better off using something like bodymovin?

```js
var count = 505;

var counter = setInterval(timer, 10); //10 will  run it every 100th of a second

function timer() {
  if (count <= 0) {
    clearInterval(counter);
    return;
  }
  count--;
  document.getElementById("timer").innerHTML = count / 100;
}
```

```css
body {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
}

#timercontainer {
  width: 750px;
  height: 500px;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
}

#timer {
  font-size: 250px;
  transform: scale(1, 2);
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  text-align: left;
}
```

```html
<div id="timercontainer">
  <div id="timer"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: Couldn't you just set the `font-size` and `letter-spacing` to get your text to your liking instead of using `scale()`

Comment: Can you explain how you expect the text to fill the box? As in both height and width?

Comment: I would like to fill the text completely stretched out. The following link can give you an idea of how I'd like the typography to appear: http://hoverstat.es/features/barron-webster-has-a-nice-holding-page

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Why is SVG ruled out?  An SVG can be live also.

```js
var count = 505;

var counter = setInterval(timer, 10); //10 will  run it every 100th of a second

function timer() {
  if (count <= 0) {
    clearInterval(counter);
    return;
  }
  count--;
  document.getElementById("timer").textContent = count / 100;
}
```

```css
#timercontainer {
  width: 750px;
  height: 500px;
}

svg { background-color: yellow; }
```

```html
<div id="timercontainer">
  <svg width="100%" height="100%" viewBox="-1 6 36 15" preserveAspectRatio="none">
    <text id="timer" x="0" y="20" font-size="20"></text>
  </svg>
</div>
```